# Checking if an user is an admin

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. In my database I added a column called admin and if you're an admin the value is 1 and if not the value is 0. But how can i make a query in php where you select an user to check if that user is an admin?

This is what i have right now.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=id1552202_accounts', 'id1552202_thecouch', 'Fargo123');   
 $admincheck = $db->prepare(" SELECT Admin From Accounts WHERE Usernames = :username ");
              $admincheck->bindParam("username", $_SESSION['loggeduser'][0]");
  $admincheck->execute();
$admin = $admincheck->fetch();
if($admin === 0){
  echo "you're an admin";
} else {
  echo "you're not an admin";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You mentioned if you are an admin then 1 else 0 but while checking 

if($admin === 0){
  echo "you're an admin";
} else {
 echo "you're not an admin";
}

I think you are checking the opposite way for the admin
```

Comment: Damn, yeah i changed that, but it still says everyone is an admin

Answer (score 1):

you are using `if($admin === 0){` and geting false return, also need fetch from array `$admin['Admin']` also `bindParam :username` not `username`

```
 $admincheck = $db->prepare("SELECT Admin From Accounts WHERE Usernames = :username ");
 $admincheck->bindParam(":username", $_SESSION['loggeduser'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $admincheck->execute();
 $admin = $admincheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($admin['Admin'] == 1){
      echo "you're an admin";
    } 
    else {
      echo "you're not an admin";
    }
```

replace query above if you want to check if user has admin credentials with code below

```
$admincheck = $db->prepare("SELECT Usernames, Admin From Accounts WHERE Usernames = :username");
```

this method to show all admin users

```
 $admincheck = $db->prepare("SELECT Usernames From Accounts WHERE Admin = 1");

 $admincheck->execute();
 $admin = $admincheck->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($admin as $row) {

        echo $row['Usernames']. "is admin<br>";
    }
```